# Running Windows XP applications on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8, windows-vista, compatibility

In the past, people using Windows Vista could run into the problem that their Windows XP
applications would not run on the new operating system. Given that Windows 7 Ultimate
and later versions of Windows are advertised as including support for Windows XP
applications, I was wondering just how easy or how compatible such systems are
with older Windows XP applications and whether there are any issues or whether
such applications work as a charm on the newer Windows systems.

Thanks.

Comment: And the same problem can occur in Windows 7. Support isn't full, Microsoft just tries to make most programs work. This being said, I rarely see any program that fails to run on Windows 7, even without compatibility mode, unless it is very (+10 years) old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 Ultimate, along with Professional and Enterprise, support a feature called Windows XP Mode.  This is a fully-functional version of Windows XP, running as a virtual machine on top of Windows 7.  That is how full compatibility is achieved: running the XP applications on the operating system for which they were built.

Windows 8 does not support XP mode. I would suspect 8.1 does not either.

(Side note: Enterprise users, this is built on Microsoft's MED-V technology.)

Comment: Relevant: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7

Comment: I see, full Windows XP compatibility is obtained by running a full instance of Windows XP inside Virtual PC which is Microsoft's version of comparable virtualization systems such as VirtualBox, VMWare, and Parallels. Too bad support was removed from Windows 8. I wonder why? I don't see why recompiling Virtual PC to run on Windows 8 wasn't possible.

Comment: Even with XP Mode compatibility is not 100%. Although I can only think of 1 application where this was this case.

Comment: @John - I suspect it has more to do with killing off XP than some kind of inability to get it to work. Just my opinion though.